# javascript string into object/array

Tags: javascript, java, json, string, format

I'm receiving that string from java code:
`{devices:[3962], contacts:[{_userId='1', _contactId='(+1)1111111', _contactName='Name Surname'}]}` and I want to convert it into normal object, but it's not a valid JSON format. Do you have any ideas?

Or maybe somebody can help me with JAVA code.
I suppose that all the magic goes here:

```
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
    public String extractDbDump() {
        return "{devices:" + getDevices() + ", contacts:" + getContacts() + "}";
    }
    private String getContacts() {
        List<ContactItem> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACT;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ContactItem contact = new ContactItem();
                contact.userId = cursor.getString(0);
                contact.contactName = cursor.getString(1);
                contact.contactId = cursor.getString(2);
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return "" + contactList.toString();
    }
    private String getDevices() {
        List<String> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DEVICE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    deviceList.add(cursor.getString(0));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return deviceList.toString();
    }
    public class ContactItem {
        public String userId;
        public String contactId;
        public String contactName;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" +
                    "_userId='" + userId + '\'' +
                    ", _contactId='" + contactId + '\'' +
                    ", _contactName='" + contactName + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fix the source of that invalid JSON

Comment: I don't know JAVA, so I can't

Comment: But you have access to the Java code?

Comment: This is not JSON, so without some heavy string manipulation, there is no easy way to parse it.

Comment: yes, I'll add JAVA code into the question, since I can't paste it here because it's too long

Comment: @alex please don't share question code in comments? It's really hard to understand all in one line. (I know you didn't, but this is for future reference)

Comment: I'm glad you didn't write that because it's egregious. String composition to create some sort of pseudo JSON...?? What the hell.

Comment: You need to use this: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary to create proper JSON.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: @ikhvjs, thank you, but it crushed when there are no devices or no contacts

Comment: Alex, thanks for your response. However, just say crash cannot help people to solve your issue. You should try to provide some error message and which part of your program crash. Your js or your java?

Answer (score 1):

I change your java and pass JSONObject and JSONArray instead. It will return a json object for your javascript program.

```java
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    
    public JSONObject extractDbDump() {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("devices", getDevices());
        json.put("contacts", getContacts());
        return json;
    }

    private JSONArray getContacts() {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACT;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
                item.put("_userId", cursor.getString(0));
                item.put("_contactId", cursor.getString(1));
                item.put("_contactName",cursor.getString(2));
                array.put(item);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return array;
    }

    private JSONArray getDevices() {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DEVICE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    array.put(cursor.getString(0));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle the case will be to ask `Java` developers to change the format to respond with the valid JSON code. Then you could just call `JSON.parse` and that would work.

Another way will be to write some kind of code that will make it valid JSON. For that you would need to wrap every key into `"` quotes and replace `=` with `:` signs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a quick fix for the string. Something like this:

```js
var s = `{numbers:[3962], contacts:[{_userId='1', _contactId='(+1)1111111', _contactName='Name Surname'}]}`;

var obj = eval(s.replace(/=/g, ":").replace(/:\[/g, "=[")); // <-- bad practice !!!

console.log(obj);
```

But it's a bad idea. I post it just as a last resort for temporary emergency cases. Don't use it in a serious code.

**You need to fix the Java code instead.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following things.

1. `ContactItem.toString`

   ```
   public String toString() {
       return "{" +
               "\"_userId\":\"" + userId + '"' +
               ", \"_contactId\":\"" + contactId + '"' +
               ", \"_contactName\":\"" + contactName + '"' +
               '}';
   }
   ```
2. `extractDbDump`

```
public String extractDbDump() {
    return "{\"devices\":" + getDevices() + ", \"contacts\":" + getContacts() + "}";
}
```

Now the result should be `{"devices":[3962], "contacts":[{"_userId":"1", "_contactId":"(+1)1111111", "_contactName": "Name Surname"}]}`

Now you can just run `JSON.parse`.

```js
const response = `{"devices":[3962], "contacts":[{"_userId":"1", "_contactId":"(+1)1111111", "_contactName": "Name Surname"}]}`;

console.log(JSON.parse(response));
```

Comment: No, that's not how this works. https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/json.html

Comment: Apparently you should use something more advanced, but the thing is that original code already does the `toString` stuff, so what's wrong with fixing that code?

Comment: It's unreadable, error prone and bad practice.

Comment: @ChrisG, and how to do it in a correct way? Maybe, you can share some hints?

Comment: @alex _"how to do it in a correct way?"_ - Google will tell you that. You're not the first that needs some data represented as JSON -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Andreas, thank you for sharing this! I was a fool when I consider that can ask for help with not MY programming language and expecting to get some help so I don't have to delve into a new programming language and its pitfalls. 
Have a good day